# can a Common Lisp lambda function return itself?

Tags: common-lisp

Okay- this might sound silly, but actually...

Imagine, you have the idea of implementing a finite state machine with functions, representing the current state (I call them state-functions forthwith).

A state-function takes an optional input event as an argument and returns (among other things), the new state function, which (and here we are at the point of this question) can be a new state (i.e. a new state-function) or if the state has not changed... itself!

```
(defun define-state (name acceptor)
  #'(lambda (context in-event)
      (multiple-value-bind (new-state? out-events new-context)
          (funcall acceptor context in-event)
        (values
          (if new-state? new-state? !!!this lambda !!!!)
          out-events
          new-context
          name))))
```

I know, I could wiggle around the problem but having this notion intrigued me and I wonder if any of you guys knows, if and how this is possible.

The only option, I currently can think of is to not define the return value as a lambda but instead use `(labels ((state-func ...)) ...)` instead. But maybe that would be cheating already?!

Comment: You can simply return `#'define-state`. A top-level function definition allows this.

Comment: @Renzo `define-state` returns a state function - it is a builder for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is to pass the function itself as an argument, which is sort-of the U combinator.  So given

```
(lambda (self ...) ...)
```

define (I don't have an implementation to hand, so this may be broken)

```
(defun funcall/U (f &rest arguments)
  (apply f f arguments))
```

and now just call it with `funcall/U`.  In particular if your functions want to recurse they now do it with `funcall/U`:

```
(lambda (self ...) ... (funcall/U self ...) ...)
```

---

What you describe with `(defvar ...) ... (setf ...)` is essentially how Scheme's `letrec` works by the way:

```
(letrec ((x (lambda (...) ... (x ...)))) ...)
```

turns into (something like)

```
(let ((x <illegal>))
  (set! x (lambda (...) ... (x ...)))
  ...)
```

Comment: The first time all that lambda calculus stuff actually yields a practical idea for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
(defun define-state (...)
  (labels ((foo ()
             #'foo))
    #'foo)))
```

Inside the local function FOO, the name FOO is known and can reference itself. This is for example necessary such that LABELS can define recursive functions.

or

```
(defun define-state (...)
  (let (f)
    (setf f (lambda (...) ... f))
    f))
```

Comment: I mentioned that in the question. Right now, I consider using a bunch of prior `(defvar *state-1*) ...` and then use `setq` to assign them and within the lambdas to refer to their respective state function variable. The variables act then a little as if they were forward declarations.

Comment: @BitTickler : or use an local variable

Comment: Yes - but then - state machines are cyclic graphs, so the global ones have the appeal, that the transition logic can use them as well, without having chicken and egg problems.

Comment: When I asked the question, I also pondered a more "low level" aspect of it: The closure (environment and function address) might already exist at the point of the lambda definition and if one could get ones hands on that within the lambdas body...